# How to use indexOf() method on parameter?

Tags: javascript, dragula

I am using dragula.js, and using ondrop event in mycode,

```
drake.on('drop', function (el) {
    console.log(el);                       //result <div>foo bar</div>
    var n = typeof(el);                    //return object
    var x = el.indexOf("test");            //error TypeError: el.indexOf is not a function(…)
    // do another code
    })
```

I want to check if `"test"` exist on `el` parameter, but error occur. thx.

Comment: Does n return the appropriate type?

Comment: No, what I know is it return object type and as @skyline said it can't use `indexOf`

Comment: Why not console.log(n)

Comment: comment beside code is result from console.log(n). Same with console.log(x) that result is error.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be as easy as `if ('test' in el)`

Comment: does not work even if i use `foo` that exist on `el` parameter

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`indexOf` works on strings, so you need to call it using the element's text, rather than the element itself, like so:</strike>

```
el.textContent.indexOf("test");
```

**Edit:**

Looks like you want the index of the dragged element rather than matching its text:

```
[].slice.call(el.parentElement.children).indexOf(el)
```

Comment: error gone but the code does not work even if i find for `foo` that it exist in `el` parameter. it return -1.

Comment: What do you mean you want to check for "test"? The `<div>` contains the strings foo and bar, obviously "test" is not one of those. Do you mean "test" is an attribute of the `<div>`? Like `<div test="test">foo bar</div>`? What condition are you expecting to be true?

Comment: all, include attribute, tag and text. Thx for help, this question is solved i found the answer in github when i wait for answer here.

Answer (score 0):

> Use the dom. Roughly: `el.parentElement.children.indexOf(el)`

Solved - https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula/issues/209